# DateJS parsing mystery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datejs

I'm using [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) to parse user-inputted dates, and getting some strange results.

1. `Date.parse("15 Jan 2010")` returns `Fri Jan 15 00:00:00 EST 2010` (right)
2. `Date.parse("15-Apr-2010")` returns `Thu Apr 15 00:00:00 EDT 2010` (right)
3. `Date.parse("15 Apr 2010")` returns `Thu Apr 1 00:00:00 EDT 2010` (wrong)

As far as I can tell, the `d MMM yyyy` input format works fine for every month except April and August; in those two cases, it returns the first of the month no matter what day is entered. Is this a bug, or is there a logical explanation I'm missing?

Comment: well when I go to the DateJS home page and type in "15 Apr 2010", it sure seems to work ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aha: Looks like the version in the ["Download"](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/downloads/list) link is a good bit older than the [current source](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/source/browse/#svn/trunk/build). Here's the [commit that fixed this bug](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/source/detail?r=138):

> Dan Yoder fixed bug with timeContext pattern where if a date included
> "april" or "august", the parser thought the 'a' was the beginning of a time part
> (as in am/pm).

The most recent version of the EN-US script is here:
http://code.google.com/p/datejs/source/browse/trunk/build/date-en-US.js
It would be nice if the website linked to this instead of to a zip file that hasn't been updated for a couple of years.

Comment: I was looking for a fix to another bug I was getting (Date.parse('12:00 pm')) and getting the newest version from svn fixed it.  Thanks!