# Date.JS parse isBefore problem

Tags: javascript, datetime, date, google-chrome-extension, datejs

Im using date.js to compare to dates that are written in user friendly string form(Sat, 1 July 2006 12:34:14). I use this code.

```
function is_new(lasttime, newtime){
    lasttime = Date.parse(lastime);
    newtime = Date.parse(newtime);
    if(lasttime.isBefore(newtime)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Both lasttime and newtime are strings like above. When I try this i get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object Tue Dec 30 1997 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time) has no method 'isBefore'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no function named isBefore. Instead, compare the timestamps:

```
function is_new(LastTime,NewTime){
  return new Date(LastTime).getTime()<new Date(NewTime).getTime();
}

alert(is_new("Dec 30, 1997","Dec 31, 1997"));
```

Comment: I see... `datejs`... Then the question is if the library has been loaded or not.

Comment: As far as I can work out, the `isBefore()` function was added in `2008-04-25` while the build date of the downloadable `date.js` file is `Nov 2007`. So `isBefore()` is in there somewhere, but you'll have to add it yourself. I'm trying to get this to work now, and it's frustrating me.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434329/datejs-parsing-mystery/2436231#2436231 for a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is that function in the newer release. Just check out the source code at http://www.datejs.com/ or download date.js file here http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js. It worked for me.